# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation ERROR when trying to changind AD user with ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I've tryed a lot of others solutions, and I still didn't make it work. Can someone help me please.
my code is like that:
I saw something about secureString, I tryed to use it but it still didn't work.
I saw too another solution that says to use var rather than string in the variables. Didn't work
I dont know if I'm doing something wrong or if those solutions that dosoen't work.

```
public bool RedefinirSenha(string pUsuario, string pSenhaAtual, string pNovaSenha)
        {
            var NovaSenha = pNovaSenha;
            var SenhaAtual = pSenhaAtual;
            var Usuario = pUsuario;
            //string Pwd = String.Format(@"""{0}""", NovaSenha);
            //byte[] pwdCerto = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Pwd);

            try
            {
                string LDAP = myLDAPpath;
                DirectoryEntry ADcon = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP, Usuario, SenhaAtual, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                if (ADcon != null)
                {
                    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ADcon);
                    search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + Usuario + ")";
                    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                        if (userEntry != null)
                        {
                            try

                            {

                                userEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { SenhaAtual, NovaSenha }, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                                userEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0;
                                userEntry.CommitChanges();
                                userEntry.Close();
                                return true;
                            }
                            catch (Exception INex)
                            {

                                this.Erro = INex.Message + "COD:\r\n" + INex.InnerException;
                                userEntry.Close();
                                return false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                            return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Erro = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there will be no difference at runtime if you declare the variables as `var` or `string`. Using the [`var` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) lets the compiler decide what the type is. Because you're assigning a `string` to it, then it is a string too. In most cases, `var` is fine. There are only very rare cases when you need to explicitly specify the type.

Second, [`DirectoryEntry.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invoke) is defined like this:

```
public object Invoke (string methodName, params object[] args);
```

That may seem like you need to pass an `object` array, but that is not the case. The [`params` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) is a way to allow you to pass multiple parameters that get used inside the method as an array. So when you call it like this:

```
userEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { SenhaAtual, NovaSenha }, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

The first parameter is an `object` array and the second parameter is `AuthenticationTypes.Secure`, then both of those get put inside the `args` array for use inside the `Invoke` method. But that is not what `ChangePassword` looks for. If this doesn't make sense to you, read [the documentation for the `params` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) and it should help.

When you call `.Invoke("ChangePassword", ...)`, it calls the native Windows [`IADsUser.ChangePassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-changepassword) method. That takes two parameters: a `string` with the old password and a `string` with the new password - not an `object` array and an `AuthenticationTypes` value. So you should be calling it like this:

```
userEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", SenhaAtual, NovaSenha);
```

You don't need to worry about the authentication because the password can only be changed over a secure connection. In the documentation, it says it behaves the same way as (`IADsUser.SetPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-setpassword), where it attempts several different ways to achieve a secure connection for you.

---

There is another way to change the password if the `DirectoryEntry` connection is already over a secure connection. A secure connection can either be using Kerberos, which can be done using `AuthenticationTypes.Sealing` (this is best if you are on the same network as the domain controller):

```
var ADcon = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP, Usuario, SenhaAtual, AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing);
```

Or if by using LDAPS (LDAP over SSL), which you can use just by specifying port 636 in the LDAP path (this is the only way if you are not on the same network as the domain controller):

```
var ADcon = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com:636", Usuario, SenhaAtual);
```

If you do that, then you can change the password by updating the [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) attribute directly, in the very specific way it wants it (enclosed in quotes and encoded in UTF-16), like this:

```
userEntry.Properties["unicodePwd"].Remove(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{SenhaAtual}\""));
userEntry.Properties["unicodePwd"].Add(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{NovaSenha}\""));
```

This should perform slightly faster since all of the work (changing the password and setting `lockOutTime`) is done over one network request instead of two.